# My JS code with addEventHandler/click is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    //Loads all the elements and assigns event handlers
    function load()
    {
        //create and append prev button
        
        loadPeople(counter);
        
        var btnNext = document.createElement("div");
        btnNext.setAttribute("class", "button");
        btnNext.setAttribute("id", "n");
        btnNext.innerHTML = "Next"
        root.appendChild(btnNext);
        
    }
    
    function loadPeople(index)
    {
        //This creates and appends several boxes with photos to represent various people
    }
    
    function addListeners()
    {
        //Add listeners
        //Previous
         
        //Next
        var eventNextClick = document.getElementById("n");
        eventNextClick.addEventListener("onclick", next, true);
    }
    
    //This should fire when next button is clicked
    function next()
    {
        alert("This works");
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load, false)
    addListeners();
    
</script>
```

Basically...my code generates two buttons prev and next, and several boxes that show images. Disregard the boxes, right now, I am just trying to get the click event to work.

This code does not seem to produce anything clickable. Not sure where my problem is. Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
eventNextClick.addEventListener("onclick", next, true);
```

The `onclick` should just be `click`.

Remember though, in < IE9, when using `attachEvent()` to use the `on` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

`eventNextClick.addEventListener("onclick", next, true);`

You need to use `"click"` not `"onclick"`

You probably also want to set the third parameter to `false` since by default you want to use bubbling.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load, false)
addListeners();
```

Your also adding listeners directly after binding the DOM ready event. This wont work. You need to wait until `load` has fired and until the button has been generated before you invoke `addListeners`

```
function load()
{
    // snip

    // invoke add listeners here instead
    addListeners();
}
```

Comment: I have corrected my code, still no effect. The first two issues I knew about, just forgot to change them when I posted the code here. The latter, I am now calling addListeners in my load...still no effect